# Sql 2000 database to Sql 2005 express db

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a database that is on a SQL 2000 server, and I would like to make it a Sql 2005 express edition database.

What is needed to do in order to make that work?

/M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way would be to create a new database in SQL 2005 and import all the objects in.

You can also backup and restore into the SQL 2005 environment.  That will work as well